# How to use plugin in Qt Application?

Tags: qt

I’ve been reading chapter 21 of `c++ gui programming with qt-4 2ndedition”` but I can’t use its simple plugin for an application . For example `bronzestyleplugin` plugin is used for `bronze` application but how use the `bronzestyleplugin` plugin for `bronze`?
Please help.
The source code is [here](http://www.4shared.com/rar/D9QVCDCG/chap21.html)

Comment: Why can't you use it? What errors are you getting?

Comment: It has no error but when I run the plugin it pops up a dialog and shows me 3 fields that one of them the first one is about executing file when I give it the path of bronze application it just run it, like running bronze project.